# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar archivos de un programa al cerrarlo y volverlo a cargar?

Tags: python, archivo, clase

Estoy aprendiendo a generar archivos.txt y a como escribir y leerlos, el problema que tengo ahora es que quiero realizar un programa en el cual pueda crear, editar y borrar personajes y que aparezcan similar a una tabla y que estos personajes nuevos se guarden en el archivo.txt

Viendo que los personajes tenían atributos en común pensé en utilizar clases, la verdad no soy experto en eso pero un poco se, mi idea principal era pedir los atributos y que se generara una objeto y este se añadiera a una lista de personajes, al hacerlo de ese modo todo va bien pero no se quedan guardados los datos al iniciar de nuevo el programa

```
class PLAYER:
    def __init__(self,Nombre,Ataque,Defensa,Vida):
        self.Nombre=Nombre
        self.Ataque=Ataque
        self.Defensa=Defensa
        self.Vida=Vida

options=[0,1,2,3]
personajes=[]

while True:
    contador=0
    archivo = open("personajes.txt","w")
    print("ID|NOMBRE|ATAQUE|DEFENSA|VIDA")
    while contador != len(personajes):
        print("(",contador,")", personajes[contador].Nombre,personajes[contador].Ataque,personajes[contador].Defensa,personajes[contador].Vida)
        contador += 1
    print("Gestor de Personajes")
    print("( 0 ) Crear")
    print("( 1 ) Editar")
    print("( 2 ) Borrar")
    print("( 3 ) Salir")
    while True:#Escoje tú opción
        try:
            opción=int(input("-> "))
            while opción not in options:
                print("¿Buscas encontrar más opciones?, lo siento amigo, no hay presupuesto para eso")
                opción=int(input("-> "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Por favor escribe el número entre parentesis de la opción que quieras hacer")
        
    if opción==3:#Cerrar
        archivo.close()
        break
    elif opción==0:#Crear
        NAME=input("¿Cuál será su nombre? ")
        while True:#Ataque
            try:
                ATACK=int(input("¿De cuanto será su ataque? "))
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")
        while True:#Defensa
            try:
                DEFENSE=input("¿De cuanto será su defensa? ")
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")
        while True:#Vida
            try:
                HEALTH=input("¿Cuanta vida tendrá? ")
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")
        personajes.append(PLAYER(NAME,ATACK,DEFENSE,HEALTH))
    elif opción==1:#Editar
        print("¿Qué personaje quieres editar?")
        ID=int(input("-> "))
        personajes.remove(personajes[ID])
        NAME=input("¿Cuál será su nuevo nombre? ")
        while True:#Ataque
            try:
                ATACK=int(input("¿De cuanto será su ataque? "))
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")
        while True:#Defensa
            try:
                DEFENSE=input("¿De cuanto será su defensa? ")
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")
        while True:#Vida
            try:
                HEALTH=input("¿Cuanta vida tendrá? ")
                break
            except:
                print("por favor pon un valor entero")     
        personajes.append(PLAYER(NAME,ATACK,DEFENSE,HEALTH))
    elif opción==2:#Eliminar
        print("¿Qué personaje quieres eliminar?")
        ID=int(input("-> "))
        personajes.remove(personajes[ID])
```

Hasta este punto no había utilizado el archivo.txt, para no mostrar el código completo denuevo solo voy a poner las partes que cambie

```
    contador=0
    archivo = open("personajes.txt","w")
    print("ID|NOMBRE|ATAQUE|DEFENSA|VIDA")
    while contador != len(personajes):
        a=("(",contador,")", personajes[contador].Nombre,personajes[contador].Ataque,personajes[contador].Defensa,personajes[contador].Vida)
        archivo.write(a)
        archivo.write("\n")
        contador += 1
    archivo.close()
    archivo = open("personajes.txt","r")
    print(archivo.read())
    print("Gestor de Personajes")
    print("( 0 ) Crear")
    print("( 1 ) Editar")
    print("( 2 ) Borrar")
    print("( 3 ) Salir")
```

El problema que aquí encontré es que el argumento de write debe de ser str, no tuple pero al poner

```
a=str("todo lo demás")
```

me aparece

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)
```

Entonces por ahora me quede sin ideas para encontrar la forma de solucionarlo, espero me puedan ayudar a resolver esto ya que no pude encontrar la solución por mi cuenta

Usando una f-string

```
    contador=0
    archivo = open("personajes.txt","w")
    print("ID|NOMBRE|ATAQUE|DEFENSA|VIDA")
    while contador != len(personajes):
        a=f"( {contador} ) {personajes[contador].Nombre} {personajes[contador].Ataque} {personajes[contador].Defensa} {personajes[contador].Vida}"
        archivo.write(a)
        archivo.write("\n")
        contador += 1
    archivo.close()
    archivo = open("personajes.txt","r")
    print(archivo.read())
```

Los nuevos personajes se imprimen pero al momento de cerrar el programa y volver a abrir los personajes que se crearon antes desaparecen

Comment: Debe de existir un modo de que pueda hacerlo sin usar el módulo pickle, como apenas estoy aprendiendo no me dejan usar cosas más avanzadas

Comment: No sabía que era una tarea académica. Si tienes que escribir tú mismo el código para escribir y leer de fichero, tendrás que convertir tus objetos en cadenas de texto. Una forma puede ser la que has intentado, pero la tupla debe ser convertida en última instancia en una cadena que tenga los valores separados por ejemplo por comas (o cualquier otro carácter) para poder recuperarlos luego. Eso puedes hacerlo con `",".join(a)` siendo `a` tu tupla. El resultado es una cadena que ya podrás pasar a `write()`

Comment: El problema será después la lectura, ya que `.readline()` te devolverá una línea que será una cadena con una serie de datos separados por comas. Deberás usar `cadena.split(",")` para separarlo de nuevo en varios trozos obteniendo una lista, y después usar los elementos de esa lista para instanciar uno de tus objetos.

Comment: Me va a explotar la cabeza jajajaja

Comment: @Santiago. Explora la técnica descrita por abulafia en un programa separado, que sólo grabe 5 datos arbitrarios y luego los lea de vuelta y reconstruya los 5 datos originales. Después podras integrar eso en tu pgma principal. Dividir para reinar, una cosa a la vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Escribir a fichero

Una opción sencilla puede ser recorrer tu lista de personajes y cada uno de ellos convertirlo a una cadena en la que los campos (nombre, etc.) aparezcan en un orden prefijado, y separados entre sí por un carácter que tú elijas, como por ejemplo `"|"` para poder separar luego por ese carácter cuando leas.

Esto se podría hacer así por ejemplo:

```
archivo = open("personajes.txt", "w")
for personaje in personajes:
   linea = f"{personaje.Nombre}|{personaje.Ataque}|{personaje.Defensa}|{personaje.Vida}\n"
   archivo.write(linea)
archivo.close()
```

De hecho podrías programar para esto una función que se llame por ejemplo `guardar_personajes()` a la que pasarías como parámetros la lista de personajes y el nombre del fichero, para que fuera más genérica.

Observa que no guardo en el fichero el índice (contador) de cada personaje, pues realmente no se necesita para nada al hacerlo así.

### Leer de fichero

A la hora de leer puedes iterar por el fichero y cada iteración te devolverá una línea (que será una cadena). Cada línea la separas por el carácter `"|"`, que es el que usamos al escribir, y cada "trozo" será un atributo del personaje. Entonces instanciarás un objeto de tipo `PLAYER` pasándole como parámetros esos atributos (tal vez haya que convertir algunos de ellos a entero), y el objeto que así has creado lo metes en la lista de personajes, que comenzaría estando vacía pero se va llenando con lo que leas del fichero.

Es decir:

```
personajes = []  # Inicialmente vacía
archivo = open("personajes.txt", "r")
for linea in archivo:
   trozos = linea.split("|")
   personaje = PLAYER(trozos[0], int(trozos[1]), int(trozos[2]), int(trozos[3]))
   personajes.append(personaje)
archivo.close()
```

Al igual que antes, esto podría ser una función que reciba como parámetro el nombre de fichero y retorne como resultado la lista `personajes`.

**Nota**. He observado que en el código de la pregunta no usas bucles `for`, sino `while`. Quizás es que aún no has dado los bucles `for`. La escritura se podría hacer entonces con un `while` similar al que tú planteabas, usando un contador como índice (aunque sigue sin ser necesario guardar ese contador en el fichero). La lectura, sin `for` sólo se me ocurre hacerla con un `archivo.readlines()` que te devuelve una lista con todas las líneas leidas. Podrías iterar sobre esa lista con un `while` para ir "partiendo en trozos" cada línea y guardarla en tu lista de jugadores, de forma similar a como hice yo, pero accediendo a cada línea a través de la lista de líneas devueltas por `archivo.readlines()`, usando un contador como índice para acceder a cada línea.

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa, complementaria a abulafia, es agregar métodos de serialización a tu clase.

Concretamente, definiremos dos métodos:

1. `to_str()`, que retorna el objeto convertido a un string csv.
2. `from_str()`, que puebla el objeto a partir del string generado por `to_str()`.

El string en cuestion lo tienes que grabar en un archivo o base de datos para conservarlo, y luego leerlo para recuperar el objeto original.

Tu clase queda asi:

```
class PLAYER:
    def __init__(self,Nombre="",Ataque=0,Defensa=0,Vida=0):
        self.Nombre=Nombre
        self.Ataque=Ataque
        self.Defensa=Defensa
        self.Vida=Vida

    def to_str(self):
        """ Serializa el objeto a un string.

        @return: String csv
        """
        return "%s,%d,%d,%d" % (self.Nombre, self.Ataque, self.Defensa, self.Vida)

    def from_str(self, as_string):
        """ Deserializa un string para poblar este objeto.

        @param as_string: Un string csv con los datos del jugador.
        """
        self.Nombre, Ataque, Defensa, Vida = as_string.split(",")
        self.Ataque = int(Ataque)
        self.Defensa= int(Defensa)
        self.Vida = int(Vida)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player %s, ataque=%d, defensa=%d, vida=%d" % (self.Nombre, self.Ataque, self.Defensa, self.Vida)
```

Nota 1: modifique el constructor para poder generar un player con puros valores por default.

Nota 2: Agregue la función mágica `__str__`, para poder imprimirlos y ver que contiene.

**Comprobación**

Programa de prueba

```
# Generamos un primer jugador e imprimimos para chequearlo.
player1 = PLAYER("Juan Perez", 10, 20, 30)
print(player1)

# Aqui lo serializamos
ser = player1.to_str()
print("Player1 serializado=", ser)

# Construimos un player2, vacio
player2 = PLAYER()
print(player2)

# Y lo poblamos a partir del string serializado de player 1
player2.from_str(ser)
print("Ahora player2 es ", player2)
```

produce

```
Player Juan Perez, ataque=10, defensa=20, vida=30
Player1 serializado= Juan Perez,10,20,30
Player , ataque=0, defensa=0, vida=0
Ahora player2 es  Player Juan Perez, ataque=10, defensa=20, vida=30
```